# Why is the metric tensor (and other bilinear forms) a $(0,2)$ tensor?

Tags: tensors

I get that we can prove that the coordinates of a bilinear form tranform by using $2$ Jacobian (or $2$ Forward) tranforms. However my learning source says that a vector is  $(0,1)$ tensor and we know that vectors transform contravariantly .
So how come a bilinear form is not called a $(2,0)$ tensor which would be more in line with a covector being a $(1,0)$ tensor and a vector being a $(0,1)$ tensor?

Comment: Usually the first arity is the number of contravariant factors, and the second is for covariant factors. So a vector is a (1,0)-tensor (one contravariant index), covector is a (0,1)-tensor (one covariant), and a bilinear form is a (0,2)-tensor (twice covariant).

Comment: thanks yes this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you mean the right thing, when you say

> However a vector tranforms covariantly and is a (0,1)  tensor and its
> co-ordinates transfrom contravariantly

You probably know that a vector $v\in M$ can be represented in a vector space $V$ by using a basis $\{e_1,...e_n\}$ of that space, i.e.
$$v=\sum_i v^i e_i$$

The matrix that maps the components $v^i$ to the components $w^i$, such that
$$v\equiv \sum_i v^i e_i \equiv \sum_j w^j f_j$$

for $w^j\in W$ is the inverse of the matrix that maps the basis vectors $e_i$ to $f_i$.

Lets call the way the basis vectors are mapped/transformed the "covariant" way (and vice versa), and lets call these objects (0,1)-tensors (or (1,0)-tensors for contravariant objects).

A (0,2) tensor is an object requiring two of covariant transformations, so that its components are represented in another basis. But the basis of this object itself transforms the other way (=the contravariant way).

Such an object can look like this:
$$T = T_{ij} e^{i}\otimes e^j$$

How I understand your question is, that you might have confused how tensors are categorized meaning, whether a (1,0)-tensor now has covariant components, or a covariant basis. Basically all this is just an (arbitrary?) convention, but I have seen people use this differently. Just be consisent with it, and explain what you mean, and use the right transformation rules, then it doesnt matter whether your you call your covariant vector a (1,0) or a (0,1) tensor.

Comment: Suggestion: ask the asker for clarification, to better understand where they are stuck, *before* guessing at where the confusion lies, and guessing at an answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think to be consistent, you would either need vectors as (0,1) , covectors as (1,0) and then bilinear forms as (2,0) OR vectors as (1,0) , covectors as (0,1) and then bilinear forms as (0,2) (as Vladimir Lysikov commented above) ?

Comment: Yes of course, if you introduce $(m,n)$ -tensors, then the choice of what $m$ and $n$ mean (i.e. whether $m$ describes the number of covariant or the number of contravariant transformations you apply and same for $n$), needs to be consistent for all the tensors that you introduce.

My point was, that I have seen some people defining a $(1,0)$ tensor as a vector and others defining a $(1,0)$ -tensor as a covector before.

Comment: And yes you are right, re-reading my original question I see it was very confused. I meant a basis element maps covariantly (by definition) and a vector requires 1 contravariant transformation, so that its components are represented in another basis. Thanks for helping me put this correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Let ${M}$ be a smooth manifold. Then, a $({m},{n})$ tensor field ${T}$ is an object
\begin{align*}
{T}\in{}&\Gamma^{\infty}({M},({T}{M})^{\otimes{m}}\otimes({T}^{\star}{M})^{\otimes{n}})\\[0.5em]
&=\lbrace{T}\colon(\Gamma^{\infty}({M},{T}^{\star}{M}))^{m}\times(\Gamma^{\infty}({M},{T}{M}))^{n}\rightarrow{C}^{\infty}({M}){\,}\vert{\,}{T}{\,}\mathrm{is}{\,}\mathrm{multilinear}{\,}\mathrm{in}{\,}{C}^{\infty}({M})\rbrace{\,}{.}
\end{align*}
A vector field ${X}\in\Gamma^{\infty}({M},{T}{M})$ is a $({1},{0})$ tensor field that has contravariant component functions, and a covector field $\omega\in\Gamma^{\infty}({M},{T}^{\star}{M})$ is a $({0},{1})$ tensor field that has covariant component functions. The covariant metric ${g}$ is an inner product on $\Gamma^{\infty}({M},{T}{M})$, i.e. a map
\begin{align*}
{g}:\Gamma^{\infty}({M},{T}{M})\times\Gamma^{\infty}({M},{T}{M})\rightarrow{C}^{\infty}({M}){\,}{,}
\end{align*}
that is multilinear in ${C}^{\infty}({M})$, symmetric in its entries and satisfies the nondegeneracy condition. Therefore, we can say that the covariant metric is indeed a tensor field ${g}\in\Gamma^{\infty}({M},\mathrm{Sym}^{2}({T}^{\star}{M})):=\lbrace{T}\in\Gamma^{\infty}({M},{T}^{\star}{M}\otimes{T}^{\star}{M}){\,}\vert{\,}{T}\langle{X},{Y}\rangle={T}\langle{Y},{X}\rangle{\,\,}\forall{X},{Y}\in\Gamma^{\infty}({M},{T}{M})\rbrace$. Similarly, the contravariant metric ${G}$ is an inner product on $\Gamma^{\infty}({M},{T}^{\star}{M})$, i.e. a map
\begin{align*}
{G}:\Gamma^{\infty}({M},{T}^{\star}{M})\times\Gamma^{\infty}({M},{T}^{\star}{M})\rightarrow{C}^{\infty}({M}){\,}{,}
\end{align*}
that is, again, multilinear in ${C}^{\infty}({M})$, symmetric in its entries and satisfies the nondegeneracy condition. Therefore, we can, again, say that the contravariant metric is indeed a tensor field ${G}\in\Gamma^{\infty}({M},\mathrm{Sym}^{2}({T}{M})):=\lbrace{T}\in\Gamma^{\infty}({M},{T}{M}\otimes{T}{M}){\,}\vert{\,}{T}\langle\omega,\eta\rangle={T}\langle\eta,\omega\rangle{\,\,}\forall\omega,\eta\in\Gamma^{\infty}({M},{T}^{\star}{M})\rbrace$.